# GeoLocation prompt does not appear in Mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, geolocation, prompt

Here I am trying to implement Permissions in Geolocation API
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API)

I am facing with the problem that i do not get Notification prompt for Location access in mobile browser (firefox,chrome):[screenshot desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw467.jpg)

Tried the live sample page in the example hosted @ https://chrisdavidmills.github.io/location-finder-permissions-api/ in which everything works fine.

But when Added same code in [src](https://github.com/chrisdavidmills/location-finder-permissions-api), inside nginx serverlet and accessed from mobile browser (chrome), I don't get notification !!!

Ideally the github example should show the prompt,but it does not show in Mobile Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved : permission allowed in Https now !